# Set seprate css reference in view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, reference

I have a layout with some css references and i want to set some css reference only for views. when i referenced it in view it's applied to layout too. 
is there any way?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}
<link href="/Content/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"   rel="stylesheet">
<div id="view">
    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
        همکار گرامی لطفا جهت دریافت فیش حقوقی کلیک کنید
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/">دریافت</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS =>
#view {
(bootstrap rtl codes)
}

Answer (score 0):

CSS is applied by the browser, client-side.  And the browser has no concept of "layout" vs. "view".  In the browser it's all one document, and the styling rules apply to that document.

What you can do is use those styling rules to target specific parts of the document.  For example, if your "view" is wrapped in a `<div>`:

```
<div id="myView">
  <!-- the rest of your view -->
</div>
```

Then in the CSS you can target all of your rules to only elements within that `<div>`:

```
#myView a {
  /* rules targeting links in the view */
}

#myView button {
  /* rules targeting buttons in the view */
}

/* etc. */
```

Comment: my css that i want to reference in views is bootstrap-rtl and i put it all in a #view but not working

Comment: my layout  is using normal bootstrap but i want to use rtl in my views

Comment: @sobhanparsa: Did you update the CSS targets to specify the containing element as suggested?  If you have an example of a simple page which has CSS rules that are "not working" then you can update the question with a code snippet to demonstrate.

Comment: i put all of the bootstrap in #view

Comment: @sobhanparsa: But did you update the CSS code as well?  The update you've made to the question contains no CSS code.  Claiming "I did it" and "it doesn't work" demonstrates nothing about the problem.

Comment: @sobhanparsa: Now what you have is invalid CSS code.  The string `"(bootstrap rtl codes)"` is not valid CSS.  The fact that there are no valid styling rules in your code definitely explains why no valid styling is being applied.

Comment: I Meant Bootstrap Left To Right Styles are there

Comment: @sobhanparsa: Consider what you're suggesting at this time... Instead of showing the modified code to this community, you just want us to assume that it's correct.  If we are to assume that everything you've written is correct then there is no problem to be solved.  Please drop your assumptions and start examining your code.  Carefully read the suggestion in this answer, specifically the CSS targets (e.g. `#myView button`), and carefully examine the code you're using to see if you've modified it as suggested. If you think you have and something isn't working, include that code in the question.